# Cannot have a fresh state in my async function React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I am working on a `QrCodeScanner` component, and every time I do a scan, I would like to check a couple of instructions and then modify the state of a `useState()`.
But actually, my state stays the same inside of my function, so the conditions pass all the time. Any idea how to work on that?

```
  /On Scaning box
  const updateBoxes = async (boxExternalId: string) => {
    if (collectDatas.scanMode === "add") {
      const boxAvailable = await getBox(boxExternalId).then(
        (response) => response.resource.status == "AVAILABLE"
      );

      if (!boxAvailable) {
        return addNotification({
          type: "error",
          title: "La boite sélectionnée n'est pas disponnible",
        });
      }

      if (collectDatas.boxes.includes(boxExternalId)) {
        return addNotification({
          type: "error",
          title: "La boite a déjà été scannée",
        });
      }

      setCollectDatas((prevCollectDatas) => ({
        ...prevCollectDatas,
        boxes: [...prevCollectDatas.boxes, boxExternalId],
      }));
    }else{
      //instruction in the case scan Mode is "remove"
      
    }
  };
```

I tried to use a callback function to set my state but the state remained the same.